# How to execute jar command with file name from java

Tags: java, jar

I need to execute jar file from java with following command.

```
java -jar test.jar >> /home/jarlogfile/test.log &
```

Its not working me. Cannot create test.log file in that location and process also end.

Coding:

```
    public static void main(String ar[]){
    ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "/home/jar/test.jar", ">> /home/jarlogfile/test.log &");
    Process p = process.start();
}
```

Help me.

Comment: How about ` new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "java", "-jar", "/home/jar/test.jar", ">>", "/home/jarlogfile/test.log")`.  Shell recognizes ">>".

Answer (score 2):

1. Makre sure main class defined in Manifest in that jar flie
2. Use getOutputStream() method of Process class to write output to file, not >> command